# SQL I need to take the max login for a specific class on a specific day in a specific position. Same person may have logged into multiple positions

Tags: sql, apache-spark, palantir-foundry

I have a table that has departure date, first name, last name, ID, classnumber, departure, arrival, position, and login timestamp. Sometimes the person logs in multiple times on the same classnumber same day but as multiple different positions. If the person has multiple positions and logins for the same classnumber then I want to take the latest one. I was originally just taking max(login) but that is allowing duplicates to still be there because sometimes the same person logs in multiple times for the same class but in different positions. How do I take max(login) and get rid of the other ones for that person on that day with different positions.

| DepDate | FirstName | LastName | ID | ClassNum | Dept | Arri | Posit | Login |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-12 | Matt | Map | ABC123 | 4532 | 05:32 | 12:34 | Line Leader | 05:00 |
| 2022-02-12 | Matt | Map | ABC123 | 4532 | 05:32 | 12:34 | Line Ender | 05:30 |
| 2022-02-12 | Matt | Map | ABC123 | 4532 | 05:32 | 12:34 | Line Middle | 04:30 |
| 2022-01-09 | Emma | Cruise | ACG123 | 4532 | 05:32 | 12:34 | Door Holder | 03:30 |

Comment: The query you tried and a sample + expected result are more useful for people to think of a solution than your description. I can also mention you may have incorrectly identified the root cause of the issue you are observing; the requested information gets rid of this possibility. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use a window to partition and order the data, create an index for the same class and same day per person log and select the first one.

```
data = [
    ['2022-02-12', 'Matt', 'Map', 'ABC123',' 4532', '05:32', '12:34', 'Line Leader', '05:00'],
    ['2022-02-12', 'Matt', 'Map', 'ABC123',' 4532', '05:32', '12:34', 'Line Ender', '05:30'],
    ['2022-02-12', 'Matt', 'Map', 'ABC123',' 4532', '05:32', '12:34', 'Line Middle', '04:30'],
    ['2022-01-09', 'Emma', 'Cruise', 'ACG123', '4532' ,'05:32' ,'12:34', 'Door Holder', '03:30']
]
cols = ['DepDate', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ID', 'ClassNum', 'Dept', 'Arri', 'Posit', 'Login']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, cols)

w = Window.partitionBy('DepDate', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ClassNum').orderBy(f.desc('Login'))

df.withColumn('rank', f.rank().over(w)) \
  .filter('rank = 1') \
  .show()

+----------+---------+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+-----------+-----+----+
|   DepDate|FirstName|LastName|    ID|ClassNum| Dept| Arri|      Posit|Login|rank|
+----------+---------+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+-----------+-----+----+
|2022-01-09|     Emma|  Cruise|ACG123|    4532|05:32|12:34|Door Holder|03:30|   1|
|2022-02-12|     Matt|     Map|ABC123|    4532|05:32|12:34| Line Ender|05:30|   1|
+----------+---------+--------+------+--------+-----+-----+-----------+-----+----+
```